# Next.js custom error page doesn't work using vercel deployment

Tags: next.js, vercel, rollbar

I'm trying to create a custom error page that will record any error to rollbar like error boundary in server side next.js

I'm following this tutorial for the `_error.js` https://maxschmitt.me/posts/error-reporting-rollbar-nextjs/

The custom error page works when I tried `run build & run start`, and the rollbar also record every error in that page

But when I deployed it using vercel, every error in server side will show this page.

My custom error page is overide by vercel error page, and the rollbar function is not working anymore.

[image: vercel 500 page]

Comment: What's in the log?

Comment: I triggered an error `map undefined`
the log just show that error

Comment: Could you show us your custom error page code?

Comment: I'm creating it same with this tutorial `_error.js` https://maxschmitt.me/posts/error-reporting-rollbar-nextjs/